# What is the best setup to keep my email private from both attackers and government agencies?

Tags: email, privacy, tor

I am attempting to setup a secure and private email account for my company. we currently use gmail which actually requests the emails from a hosting service provider that is configured with our company domain name. I would like to stop using gmail, but our hosting is not very reliable (not as much as gmail can be, but it isn't bad). and it probably isn't very secure either.

I was thinking about having a forwarder in the hosting service, not actually having anything stored in there. just forward, I think a forwarder would have a smaller probability of downtime, since it is only a service in the background of a mainframe and doesn't require storage like a fully functional email account needs.

Then I would have that forwarder send the email to at least another 2 email accounts (redundancy to counter downtime) and then a desktop email client would pull and erase the emails every 5 minutes. (this servers need to be somewhat secure, any recommendations?)

The email client would pull the emails through the TOR network to avoid tracking and everything with PGP of course.

Am I just running around and is there a better way to do this or is this not going to accomplish a private email account anyway?

Comment: If you're that concerned about your e-mail security, you need to stop worrying about who's providing the service and just start doing end-to-end encryption.

Comment: If you plan to email outside of your company, your setup might not get emails through to the recipient.

Comment: @Iszi I've set up end-to-end and it only works if the recipient is also using the same encryption.

Comment: We would use encryption among team members, but probably not with customers unless they were to send us  banking information through email we would probably request and teach them how to send encrypted emails. Mostly to avoid any liability should their info be compromised.

Comment: You might suffer problems when trying to send email to someone outside of your company, as many organization block known tor exit nodes from interacting with their mail servers.

Comment: @AntonioGarcia This is fairly common in organizations where e-mail encryption is used - internal messages are encrypted, but messages to/from the outside are not. At that point, you just need to make sure that there's nothing coming/going to/from the outside that *warrants* encryption.

Answer (score 4):

> Am I just running around and is there a better way to do this or is this not going to accomplish a private email account anyway?

It's not going to accomplish privacy from the prying eyes of major governments for a very simple reason: the e-mails sent to your company can be read from the *sender*'s outbox (perhaps even while they are being composed!).

There is no simple way to keep out major governments. It can be done, but it takes a -lot- of effort at both sides of the communication.